# How to move 5 images randomly from one point to another point out of 25 images?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, ipod

In my program I need to move 5 images out of 25 images between two random points. I am generating the image view from a class having its super class as `UIImageView`. How can I generate image view with tags or any other parameter to identify each and every image? Can any one give me a sample code or any helpful tutorial?

Comment: please make your question more specific and elaborate it clearly..

Answer (score 0):

When you generat the `UIImageView`
For example i assue this is similar to your generation

```
UIImageView *imageView = [YourGenerator generateImageView];
//Add a tag to it
imageView.tag = 1;
[self.view addSubView:imageView];
//Add another image
imageView = [YourGenerator generateImageView];
//Add a tag to it
//Different tag
imageView.tag = 2;
[self.view addSubView:imageView];
```

Now when you want to move some image, do the following

```
//Get the image view by its tag
UIImageView *imageView1 = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
UIImageView *imageView2 = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

Now move them as you wish